# Reset Constraints for the other components after removing a UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, banner-ads, safearealayoutguide

I got a banner `UIView` which I want to remove if the user has NoAds Feature.

Problem is after I remove the banner `UIView`, I cant' find a way to set the constraints of the top view to wrap the rest of `ViewController`.

Here are some images for you to better understand.

[image: StoryBoard, (Green Rectangle is the banner UIView. There's also another view above the banner UIView]

[image: The white space is when the UIView banner has been removed. I need to drag the above UIView to wrap the rest of the screen]

I remove the banner `UIView` with `removeFromSuperview()` method.

**On the storyboard, my bottom constraint is set to 0 towards the nearest neighbour which is the `UIView` banner at the time. Problem is, after I remove the Banner `UIView`, I want to set the bottom constraint of the above UIView to 0 towards the SuperView.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(myView.constraints)`

Comment: I can't seem to find a way how this could help me. I want the bottom constraint of the top UIView to change to 0 but not towards the banner UIView (which has been removed). I want it to become 0 towards the end of the SuperView.

Comment: Ok , you can try this sent fixed height  constraint to `banner UIView`
When you remove them  set  `myHeightConstraint.constant = 0  removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you can use simple solution

you can set TopView , Banner in Vertical `StackView`  with `Distribution` **Fill**
alignment **Fill**

When one of Stack-view item **Hidden** then other will Expand

See Image

[image]

If you need To  use Constrain you have `activate` and `deactivate` then call `setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: This did it! Thank you, didn't even know about this option. :P

Comment: I have a static AdManager class that keeps an array of all the banner ads. Once the user purchases, I just remove all the banners from superview by looping the array. Since the banners were all in a stack view, it automatically works.